# Soql to count How many each pick list values for picklist field in Object?

Tags: soql

I have a picklist field 3 values Like Red,Blue,White. There are 50 records in the object with different picklist values. Now I need a query - How many records with Picklist value - Red and AND how many records with Picklist value - Blue and same for the third value - White?

It should show like Picklist - Red-15 ,Picklist - Blue-10, Picklist - White-25. If it is not Possible then need a query to show all records picklist value wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of "aggregate result" query, and it looks like this:

```
SELECT SomePicklist__c value, COUNT(Id) recordCount
FROM SomeObject__c
GROUP BY SomePicklist__c
```

The output would look like this:

```
value, recordCount
Red, 15
Blue, 10
White, 25
```

You can summarize up to 2,000 values this way, which is more than enough for a single picklist.

You can read more about it in [GROUP BY | SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks sfdcfix. Can you please Provide challenging SOQLs like this

Comment: @Frank The documentation covers everything you need to know.